# Show save dialog in IE with Fine Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, uploader, fine-uploader

I am using Fine uploader to upload images. I include javascript from [GitHub](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader).
I include:

- jquery-1.8.3.min.js
- util.js
- button.js
- handler.base.js
- handler.form.js
- handler.xhr.js
- uploader.basic.js
- dnd.js

I want to use it as Fine Uploader Basic ([FUB](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-basic-demo.html)) because it's easy customize.

Below is my server code in PHP just return json:

```
$result = array("success"=>true, "id"=>"001", "name"=>"dararath");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($result);
```

It work fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 but IE 8 and 7 show save dialog instead of json.

- Does my include of javascript correct?
- Does my php json error or have any code in Fine Uploader to correct this behavior, because in it's example test on IE 7 and IE 8 work fine?

**Update (2016-07-21)**

I need to change header to solve the problem.

```
$result = array("success"=>true, "id"=>"001", "name"=>"dararath");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: You should specify a different content-type for JSON. Look at this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: I know that content-type application/json is for json, but it not work on IE 7, 8. And for this library it work like a charm. I don't know how does it do in code. i try to look the code in it but still not find yet.

Comment: Your edit should be an answer, not a change to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you download the combined version of the js.  See the [downloads section](http://fineuploader.com/downloads.html) on the home page.

Second, your problem has been covered many times in the forums and in the issue tracker.  I will go ahead and add an entry to the FAQ now as well.

Solution: Your response MUST have a content-type of "text/plain".  If you are seeing the "Save As" dialog, your response's content-type is likely "application/json".  Inspect the response carefully to verify.

Comment: It's mean that Fine Uploader is licensed plugin? so i need to pay?

Comment: Read the text at the top of the releases page.

Comment: Fine Uploader is now free open source software (MIT-licensed).